# Label Binding Exception in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have in Controller Class:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //set Properties' values at the beginning
    setProperties();
    //bind string properties to labels
    word.textProperty().bind(wordString);
    meaning.textProperty().bind(meaningString);
    sentence.textProperty().bind(sentenceString);
    //listener to detect change in index and assign strings accordingly
    DataHelper.intIndexProperty().addListener(
            (v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                wordString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("word"));
                meaningString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("meaning"));
                sentenceString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("sentence"));
                System.out.print("kjbmmj");
            }
    );
}
```

I have a class named `TimeChecker` implementing `runanble` which is instantiated and started in my `start` method in my `Main` Class. In TimeChecker Class:

```
public void run() {
    try{
        while (!isDone) {
            System.out.println("Running!!");
            System.out.println();
            DataHelper.setCurrentDate(LocalDate.now());
            if (!DataHelper.getOldDate().equals(DataHelper.getCurrentDate())) {
                DataHelper.setIntIndex(DataHelper.getIntIndex()+1);
                DataHelper.setOldDate(DataHelper.getCurrentDate());
                DataHelper.saveData();
                System.out.println("Saved!");
            }
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
        }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:438)
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:364)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$160/1022376785.call(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.access$000(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(StringPropertyBase.java:230)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
at sample.Controller.lambda$initialize$0(Controller.java:53)
at sample.Controller$$Lambda$86/694065084.changed(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(IntegerPropertyBase.java:106)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
at sample.DataHelper.setIntIndex(DataHelper.java:123)
at sample.TimeChecker.run(TimeChecker.java:26)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have this problem when the `intIndexProperty`'s `listener` fires up.
I know there are other similar questions of this problem. But I couldn't understand answers properly; I only have a vague of idea of my code breaking the rule of java, that thread other than main application thread can not change UI at any circumstances. Can anyone explain it properly and answer with required code of how I can solve this?

Comment: See [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: @VGR Can you explain in detail how I should implement that in my code? I have tried using it to run thread but still got same error.

Comment: @VGR nevermind my previous comment. It did work but my UI is not loading now.

Comment: @VGR More like my application becomes unresponsive when I use `runLater` method to run my thread although it did clear my exception problem

Comment: You're supposed to use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI, not execute your entire task.

Comment: @James_D in actuality, my thread is not even involved in updating the UI directly, I am just changing the value of integer property by thread, which, in turn, will change my StringProperty, and again which will finally bind to the label. Why is that exception even happening as my thread is not changing the UI directly?

Comment: Because you are changing a property that is bound to the UI. So when you call the set method on that property, it triggers the call to the listeners registered with it (including any registered by the binding), which update the property of the UI component, which updates the UI. So you are indirectly updating the UI, so you need to be on the FX Application Thread. You can see this in the stack trace: the lambda in your controller calls the `set` method on a `StringProperty`, which fires off a value changed event, which notifies a listener, which modifies a label.

Comment: @James_D Wow. I got what the problem is now. Thanks! But can you suggest me how I can change that thread to only make it change my UI so my program won't get unresponsive?

Comment: Isn't that already answered? Wrap the code that accesses those properties  (I think that's `DataHelper.setCurrentDate(...)` and the `if` construct) in a `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: @James_D I didn't know I was supposed to make another run method inside runLater; so I was confused. Now it all runs fine. Thanks to your "wrap only the setCurrentDate" part, I finally understood what I should do. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the line that influences GUI only, inside `Platform.runLater()` so you wouldn't make the UI unresponsive.

Like:

```
  public void run() {
    try{
        while (!isDone) {
            System.out.println("Running!!");
            System.out.println();
            DataHelper.setCurrentDate(LocalDate.now());
            if (!DataHelper.getOldDate().equals(DataHelper.getCurrentDate())) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DataHelper.setIntIndex(DataHelper.getIntIndex()+1);
                    }
                });
                DataHelper.setOldDate(DataHelper.getCurrentDate());
                DataHelper.saveData();
                System.out.println("Saved!");
            }
```